# Genymotion The VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I am trying to turn on my Genymotion emulator but I keep getting this message:

```
The VirtualBox DHCP server has not assigned an IP address to the virtual device.
```

I tried many solutions such as configurate a new Host-Only Ethernet Adapter, but it didn't solve my problem. When I tried to runthe Genymotion as administrator, it solved this problem, but I want to drag and drop files from my computer to the emulator and I cannot do it when I run it as administrator.